# EF Group By nested element and select a property of that elment

Tags: c#, entity-framework, group-by

I'm trying to get RendezVous grouped by Compagne and Date (for each Compagne I have a List of dates which every date has the count of RendezVous).

My Entities are like this:

```
class RendezVous {
  // properties....
  Compagne Compagne { get; set; }
}
class Compagne {
  // properties
  string Nom { get; set; }
```

My query is like:

```
        public static IEnumerable GetProgression()
        {
            var list = dbContext.RendezVous.GroupBy(o => new
            {
                Compagne = o.Compagne,
                Date = o.DateCreation
            }).Select(g => new
            {
                Compagne = g.Key.Compagne.Nom,
                Date = g.Key.Date,
                Total = g.Count()
            }).OrderByDescending(k => k.Date).ToList();
            return list;
        }
```

In this case the error is:

```
Column 'dbo.Compagne.Nom' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

And when I do GroupBy `Compagne = Compagne.Nom` and `Select Compagne = g.Key.Compagne.Nom` it works fine, however I might have some Compagne objects with the same Compagne.Name values.
Please help

Comment: What are you trying to do, what is the expected outcome of the query?

Comment: I'm trying to get RendezVous grouped by Compagne and Date (for each Compagne I have a List of dates which every date has the count of RendezVous)

Comment: Are you really trying to return an untyped `IEnumerable` containing anonymous objects from that `GetProgression` method?

Comment: Yes I am, you're saying like it's a crime :D

Comment: @Fourat No I am not :D It is just rather unusual. because unless you make them dynamic or serialize them there is not much you can do with them. Except count how many there are :D

Comment: @Alex I'm serializing them and sending them to DevExtreme charts ;)

Comment: I decided not to try to answer your question, because frankly I can't really see what is wrong with the query. For troubleshooting purposes, have you tried making making it less complex, e.g. group by only the `Compagne.Nom` field?

Comment: Yes I did however I may have some Compagne objects that have the same Compagne.Name property, so the grouping won't work perfectly if I do it by Compagne.Nom. The problem I think is that EF is Compagne child attributes in the Select stage